# Android APK crashes at activity but it works when running it from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, flutter, apk, jcenter

I'm developing an app on Flutter. There's this button in the Flutter code that when I press it I go to a native activity on Android as it uses a specific library only available there (`JCenter` repo).

This works perfectly fine when I plug my phone to the PC and run it through Android studio, but when I create the APK, install it on the same phone and press the button to go to the native activity it crashes. I've ran `adb logcat` when this happens and the error I see that could cause the crash is `NoSuchMethodError: no static method "libraryName;methodName"`.

I imagine the APK doesn't load the specific library from `JCenter`, but I can't find a single reason why that would happen, or how to make it work. Or maybe I'm completely wrong and this isn't what's happening, but I'm at a loss.

Why would that happen or how to find out more that would help me fix it?

The library is called `wifination`. The method of the error is `OnSave2ToGallery`. I've found out also exactly where in my code it crashes (copied from their sample code), and it's when I do `wifination.appContext=getApplicationContext()` in the `onCreate()` method of the Activity. `appContext` is `public static Context appContext` in the `wifination` class.

A bit more of the error:

```java
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.my.app, PID: 30468
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lcom/joyhonest/wifination/wifination;.OnSave2ToGallery(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Runtime.java:1121)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1075)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1656)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.joyhonest.wifination.wifination.<clinit>(Unknown Source:15)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.my.app.MyActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:36)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8057)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8037)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1344)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3688)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:550)
09-29 18:19:32.853 30468 30468 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
09-29 18:19:32.856  1340  7072 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.my.app/.MyActivity
09-29 18:19:32.856  1340 30620 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
09-29 18:19:32.858  1340  7072 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.my.app/.MainActivity
09-29 18:19:32.859  1340  1562 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
09-29 18:19:32.860  1340  1562 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
```

Comment: Assuming [this is the "wifination" thing](https://github.com/aivenlau/Wifi_Camera/) you mentioned (you have not provided the link) then I would assume you are trying to run it in an x86 emulator but this library has only an armv7 and armv8 code library included, so you need to run it in an emulator with arm supports (e.g. the recent images with Google Play support should have support for arm).

Comment: @Robert no no, I'm using my own phone on Android studio, no emulators. The thing is that when I press the run button on Android Studio, it installs the app on my phone and it works perfectly fine. Then I just build the apk out of the code and install it on the same phone and crashes. What I don't understand is why it works when installing through Android Studio but not through APK

Answer (score 0):

It was R8 that wasn't including the `private static` methods of the library. I added them in the `proguard-rules` file and it works fine.